# Handling a big matrix in R

Tags: r, memory-management, ff, bigdata

I have a very large Term Document Matrix in R with dimensions 81094 * 14177. 
On trying to convert it to a normal matrix I am getting an error

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 8.6 Gb
```

The code that I have used is

```
new_matrix = as.matrix(old_matrix).
```

Is there a way to handle such situations in R where memory is insufficient?

Comment: It would help if you could inform us on the data type of the TDM you are trying to convert. Generally speaking though, sparse matrices (`Matrix` package; note the capital letter) are the answer, since there are many zeroes in a TDM.

Comment: The class is "TermDocumentMatrix"    "simple_triplet_matrix"

Comment: When I am using object.size on the old_matrix I am getting a size of 0.21 GB

Comment: The reason is that the TDM is using a sparse format (hence the `simple_triplet_matrix` format), not saving in memory the many, many zeroes. `matrix` to the contrary is not sparse and does save all the zeroes. `Matrix` is sparse if you use the `sparse=TRUE` argument - so you should try that.

Comment: @mpjdem- thanks a ton. will surely try this